# Robocopy complex exclude

Tags: robocopy

How can I have robocopy exclude any file with `a` in the filename, *unless* it also has `b`?

EG Exclude

```
foo-a.txt
foo-a-c.txt
```

Include

```
foo-a-b.txt
foo-a-b-c.txt
```

The `/XF` switch looks like it's the most promising, but I don't know how to construct the wildcard for anything more than basic `*` style globs.

`/XF file [file]... :: eXclude Files matching given names/paths/wildcards.`

Doing something like `robocopy /mir c:\test\source\ c:\test\dest\ /XF "*a*"` results in no files being copied

Comment: @EEAA I've updated the question with what I've tried and where I'm struggling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately Robocopy has no explicit Include operator or a (known to me) options to reverse the exclude. But you can provide wildcards for the file name which *should* do what you might want.

Try:

```
robocopy <source> <dest> "*a-b*" [options]
```

Regards

Comment: I'll accept this answer as it's helpful, and the fault is with the software, not your response ;)